# How to change numeric data format for html output

Tags: python, pandas

I have code to produce a pandas dataframe and send email in html format.
The problem I have is hard to change the scientific format of numeric numbers to general in style

I already tried to set float format, but it did not work.

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:20,.2f}'.format
```

output:

```
Col A        Col B
1.00E+06    2.28E+06
3.00E+07    -2.54E+07
```

expected out:

```
Col A        Col B
1000420      2281190
30030200    -25383100
```

Comment: Whats the output when you do `df.astype(float)?`

Comment: @Wen your code is no different than I posted.

Comment: @Bharathshetty no. it does not work

Comment: what if you convert them to string in the output you sent to email

Comment: What's the dtype of columns?

Comment: @Bharathshetty they are all float

Comment: @MenglongLi it would work, but I have html style function depend on float type. I could convert data type in style function, but it looks mess, since it needs two time casting

Comment: @Bharathshetty I checked the cell and html. it seems pandas convert it to scientific format in somewhere. I will check the source code to see where it is

Comment: Did you try something like: pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.3f' % x)

Comment: @MenglongLi it is same as I posted

Comment: its working for me python v3.6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried this and it worked:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[3.371e17,9.82173e15],[8e12,8e8]],columns=['A','B'])

df.to_html(float_format='{:20,.2f}'.format)
```

This is not changing the formatting of `df` in general, just the html output, which is:

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>337,100,000,000,000,000.00</td>
      <td>9,821,730,000,000,000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>8,000,000,000,000.00</td>
      <td>800,000,000.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what is difference between your code and my post "pd.options.display.float_format = '{:20,.2f}'.format"

Comment: You are setting the display option for every representation, not only the html dump. What you did worked for me, but is more pervasive. If this is not working, I need to know in which way is not working for you

Comment: any chance you saw my post. it is not working for the email I send out.

Comment: In which way is it not working? What are you sending via e-mail?

Comment: I am using smtplib. the number in html table did not change the format even I set the format for float

Comment: Can you add to your question the result of df.to_html()?

Comment: I am also using style to set other attributes, not only numeric format, thus I can not just call to_html

Comment: the first table I posted is the result

Comment: You should consider adding all these details to the question.

Comment: the other style attributes would not impact the numeric format

Comment: instead of df.to_html, replace with df.to_string ?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't reproduce your problem with the example you stated. It might be something that changes the dataframe format within your code. But I believe this code can help you:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Col A":[1000420, 30030200],"Col B": [2281190, -25383100]})
for col in df:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: "%.f" % x)
```

With this you get as output:

```
>>> df
      Col A      Col B
0   1000420    2281190
1  30030200  -25383100
```

Comment: I think this can help in OP's issue, since it returns the float values.